# Mac Chrome and Mac Safari produces different unicodes

Tags: java, spring, grails, unicode

I'm working on a legacy project where we use Java 6 with Spring, Grails, etc.

The problem I'm running into, is that I have an file upload form, where we support support German filenames.
In this case I have a file named something with "für" and I'm having difficulties with that now.

I have tried converting it to unicode to see if that solved the problem but I am now able to see why there's a problem.
On Mac Chrome, it produces U+308 while on Mac Safari it produces U+00FC, with Safari it works and inserts correctly in MySQL, the other one fails.

The error from MySQL:

```
#1366 - Incorrect string value: '\xCC\x88r' for column `name` at row 1
```

When I try running this code:

```
UPDATE `X` SET `name` = 'für' WHERE `skabelon`.`id` = 1302
```

Why is there a difference and how can I fix it so it'll work with Chrome on Mac? Windows and Ubuntu Chrome works flawless.

**UPDATE**
It's now working after Normalizing the string.

Comment: There are many representation of Unicode characters. You should normalize, else you will have surprises. In such case, one use the normalization form with decomposition (so u and " as two codepoints, the later as composing character), and one the composing normalization. Things are more complex if you have multiple accents, or different scripts. So: normalize strings before to handling them. Note: unicode equality should handle things correctly, but not if you check byte per byte.

Comment: What do you mean by "it fails"?  What actually happens?  (I agree that the solution will be to normalize the text.)

Comment: Didn't know about Normalizer, but it did solve my problem! @StephenC The failing part was MySQL complaining about the string since it couldn't insert the combining character

Comment: Yes ... but what exactly does it say.  Add the complete error message to your question.  It will help other people ... and might encourage someone to write a proper answer to this question.

Comment: @StephenC good call! It's updated with more details :) Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after I put it through normalizing in Java. Never knew that I needed that before now.

I used the Normalizer from java.text

```
Normalizer.normalize("String",  Normalizer.Form.NFC)
```

Comment: Please consider to provide a code example to this answer, as it would greatly benefit other users with the same problem. Thanks!